# How to get the device id from watch os swift

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

Hey I am developing a watch application and I want to get the device id of the device. But when I try to access using "UIDevice.current" it gives an error that UIDevice is not within scope. Am I doing something wrong or is it somehow restricted for obtaining those information? How can I obtain that information? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Apple doesn't want you getting a unique fixed id for a device because it's an invasion of the user's privacy to track them with such an id.  What are you trying to do?  Perhaps there is another way to do what you want to do (assuming it's not privacy invading tracking).

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8rm6injj for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is also stucked with the above scenario,You can easily achieve the device id by

```
let deviceId = WKInterfaceDevice.current().identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? ""
```